# How do I merge adjacent SPAN tags in an XML document?

Tags: xml, dom, powershell, html

We have some XML documents that contain a bit of XHTML in bits.  The HTML has come out of MS Word or something and there's lots of adjacent SPAN tags that are exactly the same, except for their content.

I've been loading the XML into powershell and comparing adjacent nodes and so on but this seems laborious and has a high potential for errors.  Is there a smart way to do this via XML DOM or HTML DOM?

Comment: Can you show some sample XML and PowerShell code you're currently using?

Comment: The XML looks something like this:
<span style="font-family:Verdana;font-size:10pt;" />
<span style="font-family:Verdana;font-size:10pt;">Some</span>
<span style="font-family:Verdana;font-size:10pt;">of your company’s mobile sales representatives</span>
<span style="font-family:Verdana;font-size:10pt;">use portable computers that</span>
<span style="font-family:Verdana;font-size:10pt;">run</span>
<span style="font-family:Verdana;font-size:10pt;">Microsoft Office Outlook 2007</span>
<span style="font-family:Verdana;font-size:10pt;">and</span>

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with:

```
function removeNode($mynode){
    $parent = $mynode.get_parentNode()
    $parent.removeChild($mynode)
}

function parseStyles($mySpans){
    $global:finished = $true
    foreach($span in $mySpans){
        if($span.('#text') -eq $null -and !$span.haschildnodes){
            removeNode $span
        }
        elseif($span.get_NextSibling() -ne $null){
            if($span.get_NextSibling().style -eq $span.style){
                $span.get_innerText()+$span.get_NextSibling().get_InnerText()
                $span.'#text' = $span.get_innerText()+$span.get_NextSibling().get_InnerText()
                $span.('#text')
                removeNode $span.get_NextSibling()
                $global:finished = $false
            }
        }
    }
    return $mySpans
}
$global:finished = $true
$files = get-childitem -recurse -include "*.xml"

foreach($file in $files){

    [xml]$inputXML = Get-Content($file.directory.name+'\'+$file.name)
    do{
        $Spans = $inputXML.selectnodes('//span')
        parseStyles($Spans)
    }until($global:finished)
    $inputXML.save('./desktop/prometric/'+$file.directory.name+'/processed_'+$file.name)
}
```